# What subpanel and number of circuit breakers should I install in a detached garage?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, garage, subpanel

I no longer am dealing with my contractor. Long story.  But he ran 2 10-3 wires out to my garage for power.  I think he was planning on putting a 30 amp breaker on the panel in the house for each wire and a sub panel in the garage for each wire.  Is this OK to do?  If so, what kind of sub panel should I get? How many breakers can run on each sub panel?

Comment: This really needs to start with your requirements.  Is this a new garage, or adding capacity to an existing garage?  What sort of equipment are you planning on using in the garage?

Comment: Also need to know how far from the main panel to the subpanel because you have to de-rate the ampacity of the wire because of its resistance.

Comment: I need lights, some outlets.  I may run a compressor at some point but just a home owner size, nothing commercial. The garage doesnt have any electricity in it now. It is about 150 ft from the house.  The wires are already run in conduit underground and come up at the garage.  It is a very old garage/barn.

Comment: I planned on running florescent lighting, about 8 fixtures. These have actually been wired in just not hooked up yet.          I guess, what Im asking is, if I put a 30 amp breaker in my house's main panel and connect one of the 10-3 wires to it, and run it to a sub panel in the garage where I will put 2 or 3 15amp or 20amp breakers, and run the lights and outlets off of those breakers, is it ok????

Answer (score 3):

You or your contractor have gone about this backwards. The first step is to determine your electrical requirements, including a reasonable amount of future expansion. Then you can size the wire & breaker together to meet those requirements.

Comment: I planned on running florescent lighting, about 8 fixtures. These have actually been wired in just not hooked up yet.

Comment: I planned on running florescent lighting, about 8 fixtures. These have actually been wired in just not hooked up yet.          I guess, what Im asking is, if I put a 30 amp breaker in my house's main panel and connect one of the 10-3 wires to it, and run it to a sub panel in the garage where I will put 2 or 3 15amp or 20amp breakers, and run the lights and outlets off of those breakers, is it ok????